# What's the standard way to deal with unsupported CSS expressions?

Tags: css

What does the CSS standard say about unsupported expressions? How should a browser deal with them? How do actual browser implementations deal with them?

I'm implementing a CSS **property optimizer** (for a minifier project), and we want to leave CSS fallbacks intact. Our goal is to optimize the CSS as much as possible but in such a way that **it should render exactly the same as the original**.
This is why it's essential for me to understand how these things work.

### Simple properties

For simple properties, it's really easy.
Let's say we have this:

```
div {
    color: #f00;
    color: rgba(1,2,3,.4);
}
```

In this case, if the browser doesn't support `rgba` then the first declaration `#f00` wins. There is no question here.

### Shorthands

However, how does it work with shorthand properties?
Here's some code:

```
div {
    background: #f00;
    background: rgba(1,2,3,.4);
}
```

**How does the browser render this if it doesn't understand `rgba`?** As you know, the syntax of `background` is: `background: <color> <image> <repeat> <attachment> <position>;` and such a shorthand declaration overrides any of the 5 fine-grained declarations that came before it; so the difficulty lies in which one of the 5 fine-grained properties the browser tries to assign the unknown token to. I have several possibilities in mind:

- the browser decides it doesn't understand the latter declaration at all and drops it entirely
- the browser thinks that `rgba(...)` represents a `background-image` and even though it doesn't know what to do with it, clears out the previous `background-color` as well
- the browser thinks that `rgba(...)` represents a `background-color` and since it doesn't understand it, falls back to using `#f00` instead

**Let's make it even more interesting, say we have this:**

```
div {
    background: #fff url(...) no-repeat;
    background: rgba(1,2,3,.4) linear-gradient(...) repeat-y;
}
```

**How does a browser interpret this CSS snippet, ...**

- if the browser doesn't understand `rgba`?
- if the browser doesn't understand `linear-gradient`?
- if the browser doesn't understand `repeat-y`?
- if the browser doesn't understand any two of the three?
- if the browser doesn't understand any of the three?

Comment: As what I have seen (but I can confirm it right now) IE will ignore/overwrite the the first (`background: #fff url(...) no-repeat`) even if it does not understand the second on. So either you need to be specific. Or split it up into two rules with the same selector. The specs [Rules for handling parsing errors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#parsing-errors) look like, that the property has to be completely ignored if the value is illegal for the specs version the browsers uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, if a browser cannot understand even a part of an expression, then it handles the property as syntactically wrong, and ignores the whole line.

Answer (score 6):

The parsing rules in [section 4.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#parsing-errors) of the CSS2.1 spec speaks in terms of *declarations*, which refer to entire property-value pairs, regardless of whether the properties are shorthand or not:

> - **Illegal values.** User agents must ignore a declaration with an illegal value. For example:
>
>   ```
>   img { float: left }       /* correct CSS 2.1 */
>   img { float: left here }  /* "here" is not a value of 'float' */
>   img { background: "red" } /* keywords cannot be quoted */
>   img { border-width: 3 }   /* a unit must be specified for length values */
>   ```
>
>   A CSS 2.1 parser would honor the first rule and ignore the rest, as if the style sheet had been:
>
>   ```
>   img { float: left }
>   img { }
>   img { }
>   img { }
>   ```
>
>   A user agent conforming to a future CSS specification may accept one or more of the other rules as well.

Notice that the third example shows the use of an illegal value for the `background` shorthand property resulting in the entire declaration being ignored.

Although the spec speaks of *illegal* values, as far as an implementation is concerned an unrecognized value and an illegal value are the same thing, since either way the implementation doesn't know what to do with such a value.

So the answer to the first part of your question is

> - the browser decides it doesn't understand the latter declaration at all and drops it entirely

And the answers to the second part are all the same: the latter declaration is ignored entirely.